# Postman get variable used in array find doesn't work

Tags: javascript, postman

Using the newest version of Postman.

I have a predefined variable "useridToken" which is a number: 123456

```
var useridToken = pm.environment.get("useridToken");
//console.log(useridToken);

var jsonData = pm.response.json();
const user = jsonData.find(u => u.user_metadata.employeeId === useridToken);
const userid = user ? user.user_id : 'not found';

pm.environment.set("user_id", userid);
```

Whenever I run this code, it returns errors.
The console log output is the number as an integer: 123456

Whenever I run the following code:

```
var useridToken = 123456

var jsonData = pm.response.json();
const user = jsonData.find(u => u.user_metadata.employeeId === useridToken);
const userid = user ? user.user_id : 'not found';

pm.environment.set("user_id", userid);
```

It works like a charm, but I don't want the hardcoded useridToken in my code, I would like to get it from my environment variables. I don't quite understand why the first part isn't working? What am I overseeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in your `.find` method you're using `===` comparison, and when you fetch from environment you always get it as a 'string' and not a 'number' (Postman always gives the value of the environment variable in the string format)

So when you use a `===` comparison in JS, it also checks the type of the data, here
`string` === `number` will actually be false and that's why your find doesn't work.

So, you need to update your code to actually parse the integer that you got from the environment.

This should fix your issue:

```
var useridToken = parseInt(pm.environment.get("useridToken"));
```

Comment: Even this **might fail** if the retrieved value of the property is of type string.

Comment: How would this fail? Postman will always give the environment variable as a string. He needs it as number, how will converting it to string always help? When the use-case is to always check if the numbers match or not. Why do you have to change the data-type for comparison?

Comment: The OP ultimately wants to compare the values. So I have just given an another way to avoid the OP's error.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

Since you are using **=== operator**, it checks for the type of the variables too. The type for both operands might be different on certain scenarios. So, use the following to avoid the issue.

```
const user = jsonData.find(u => +u.user_metadata.employeeId === +useridToken); // converts to number then checks
```

or

```
const user = jsonData.find(u => u.user_metadata.employeeId.toString() === useridToken.toString()); // converts to string then checks
```

or

```
const user = jsonData.find(u => u.user_metadata.employeeId == useridToken); // checks without the operands type. (not recommended)
```

Comment: If someone downvotes, provide your reasons for that as well.